# solr overwrite on just some fields with duplicate uniquekeys

Tags: performance, solr, lucene, nutch, solrcloud

I am using nutch for crawling some pages into solr index. For the purpose of specifying The documents that are read I added a boolean value called `"read_flag"` into `"schema.xml"` with default value of false. When an application user read a document it will send a solr update query to set the solr index and set the `read_flag` to `true`. On application side I user solr query on all documents that their `"read_flag"` is false to see all the documents that are not read yet. I also defined url to be uniquekey so Solr will overwrite new documents if it finds out that its url is duplicate. My problem is when the new document is sent to solr for indexing its read_flag would be false which is overwritten to solr existing document that might have `read_flag=true`! I am thinking of some solution but all of them have some performance cost.

1) Use to different documents one for read_flag another for other parts. User solr join in query time. The problem is I am not able to use solrCloud and multi sharding in this way!

2) Changing Nutch to send update query instead of add query for every new document. Probably the performance of indexing decreases in this method. Since this is not applicable for the documents that should be insert for the first time probably it is not feasible solution.

3) Changing solr code to misses some fields for overwriting on duplicate unique-key.

4) Using solrj inside nutch to read document `read_flag` value and send it for index with this `read_flag` value.

My question would be what method is best suitable for my situation? and How can I do such method?

Rgards.

Comment: .. or store the read-flag in your application, leaving the indexing / retrieval / storage to nutch and Solr, and application logic in the application.

Comment: In this case the join over solr and that application could result problem. Also solr query paging will be inapplicable in this case.